# How to scroll up the url address bar first (on mobile browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

My site's content is in a container of height `100vh`, with `overflow-y: scroll`

The problem is that on mobile (e.g. android chrome) the url bar stays there until you scroll to the very end of all content, then it finally scrolls out of sight (because you are finally trying to drag the container up).

Is there any way to get the container to scroll up (to remove the address bar) *first*? And after that scroll through the overflow within the container?

I have tried this JS to hide the address bar on load, but it doesn't work (though I can confirm that the event triggers and the code is run, just nothing happens):

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  window.scrollTo(0,1);
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to make height 100vh? You can remove height property from style and fixed UI you want to fix with  position: fixed; and let container scroll normally

Comment: It's convenient for some other reasons, such as allowing a side navbar to not scroll with the content (though I could change that to a fixed position), and once the address bar is gone, it lets the user scroll up without the address bar coming down (until you're at the very top of the content). It makes the site feel much more like a native app than a page in a browser

Comment: As far as I know it’s impossible to hide address bar without scrolling body

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you can solve it, please post the answer and I will give you free internet points